# Connecting Heroku Database to SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, flask, sqlalchemy

so as part of a Web Programming MOOC, I have to connect to a PostgreSQL Database hosted on Heroku using Python and SQLalchemy. I have spent a lot of hours trying to do this to no avail. My main problem is that I'm not being able to connect to the Database, because every time a try to run a script to update or just check the Database I get *"Is the server running on host "ec2-174-129-35-61.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (174.129.35.61) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"* in the command prompt.

I've done a lot of research trying to figure it out and it seems that maybe the URI of my Database is not set to accept public connections. But I tried setting ssl = require and still haven't been able to solve the problem. Maybe I didn't do it right?

I have come to think that maybe I am doing something wrong with the code, or that I should try to connect through Heroku's CLI and not the command prompt but I am not sure. This is my simple test code:

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

if not os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"):
    raise RuntimeError("DATABASE_URL is not set")

engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

db.execute("INSERT INTO books VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1)")
db.commit()
```

I set the DATABASE_URL environment variable in the command prompt to the Database's URI but maybe I did it wrong? I also tried just using the URI in the code itself but still could not make it work.

This is my first time using Databases with Heroku so I am complete neewbie, maybe I am doing something else wrong?. I appreciate all the help that you guys can give. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Check, did you copied all link, including `postgres://`

2) Maybe you had made a mistake during setting DATABASE_URL. So, try to add your URL directly to the script:

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = "postgres://ennjrjkrfsb____all_code_of_key_.....___compute.amazonaws.com:5432/ddo7541ka3hio7"
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
db.execute("INSERT INTO books VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1)")
db.commit()
```

3) if you are using linux, try to open your database, using command `psql postgres://ennjrjkrfsb____all_code_of_key_.....___compute.amazonaws.com:5432/ddo7541ka3hio7`

4) Try to access to your database in any way via other internet provider (may be your provider or sys admin in your office restricted access to Heroku)

**Update**: Try to use free online IDE with interpreter (based on Linux), for example, https://cs50.io - from this site you can access to Heroku postgres

Comment: OMG thank you so much. I tried connecting to the server via my phone's Hotspot and magically was able to access the Database, then I tried again with my Wi-Fi and I couldn't. So basically my ISP has blocked the access, the thing is that I can't connect via my own home's Wi-Fi, do you think there's something I can do about that? 
Anyhow thank you so much at least I know I'm not doing anything wrong so I'll just keep on going with the assignment with some other server.

Comment: Try to use free online IDE with interpreter (based on Linux), for example, https://cs50.io - from this site you can access to Heroku posgresql.

Answer (score 1):

`postgres` dialect does not support any more in SQLAlchemy v1.4.x above, and it turns into `postgresql`, so the final connection string must be `postgresql://username:password@host:port/database`

Here is my working connection from `SQLAlchemy` to `Heroku Postgresql`

```py
database_url = os.environ('DATABASE_URL')

if database_url.startswith('postgres://'):
    database_url = database_url.replace('postgres://', 'postgresql://')

engine = create_engine(database_url)

# rest of your codes...
```

here is my reference [Heroku Issue](https://help.heroku.com/ZKNTJQSK/why-is-sqlalchemy-1-4-x-not-connecting-to-heroku-postgres)